# How to block ports on iPhone?

Tags: networking, router, proxy, iphone

I have a scenario in which some apps on iOS that use different ranges of ports to access the internet need to be tested with our proxy. I need to check how do the app and proxy behave when different ports are blocked for iPhone.

Any ideas on how to do this. Perhaps use macbook as access point for iPhone (using Internet Sharing) and block ports on mac using pfctl? Also, I looked if I could block ports on the workplace router but couldn't find an option to do that.

The setup is needed as a test environment so it doesn't matter if it can be replicated in production or not.

Comment: Do you mean block *outbound* connections from the iphone on particular ports?  If so, then you ideally need a firewall between the phone and the internet.  iphone->ap->firewall->internet and block ports on the firewall.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need to block outbound connections on particular ports. Could you elaborate on the firewall you suggest.

Comment: The approach you suggested should suffice - really, if you have something you can put in the path that can block ports, then that is your answer.  If you don't then a router with port blocking capability (which is effectively a firewall) is needed.

Comment: Hi @Paul , where is the option of iphone->ap->firewall->internet on iOS 12 currently?

Comment: @allenlinli This wasn't a setting, but a description of the network setup you would need in order to control access from an iphone to the internet.  You'd need a firewall in the path.